# Google Lens won't open a deeplinked QR code, but works on other QR scanner apps

Tags: android, qr-code, deep-linking

I'm currently working on the ability to scan a QR code that's deeplinked to open our app. It works fine on iPhone without hitches. However, on Android devices it won't work if you try to scan it using Google Lens. It attempts to search the internet, w/ no ability to open the app. However, if I scan it on another QR code app downloaded from the Play Store, then it does recognise it as a deeplink and gives the user to open.

Given that Google Lens is all but standard on Android devices, is there a reason for this behaviour? Is there anything we can do to resolve it?

Found a workaround in that if the deeplink is shortened by something like tinyurl and then open that link, it opens the app.

It's good to have this workaround but a more ideal solution would be to have no such reliance on link shortener sites.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a bug specific to the Google Lens app and Pixel devices(They also have this problem). The application treats all example://links as if the destination were a web browser

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).